# Cómo corregir el error couldn't recognize data in image file?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de cargar una imagen en python pero la tengo dentro de la carpeta del proyecto pero no me carga la imagen y manda un error

Adjunto código:

```
from tkinter import*
ventana=Tk()
ventana.geometry("700x600+0+0")
ventana.config(bg="red")
ventana.title("Ejemplo de imagenes")
imagenL=PhotoImage(file="img.jpg")
lblImagen=Label(ventana, image=imagenL) .place(x=50,y=50)


ventana.mainloop()
```

No se que este pasando pero no me carga la imagen y manda un error

Adjunto imagen del error
[image: manda ese error y no carga el programa]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El formato `jpg` no es soportado directamente por `tkinter`, podrías utilizar `PIL` (`pip install pillow`) para hacerlo:

```
from tkinter import*
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("700x600+0+0")
ventana.config(bg = "red")
ventana.title("Ejemplo de imagenes")
#imagenL = PhotoImage(file = "img.jpg")
imagenL = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('img.jpg'))
lblImagen = Label(ventana, image = imagenL).place(x = 50,y = 50)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: si me funciono muchas gracias